# How can I use translations in my data tags

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I have installed i18n into my Nuxt project, I have created the json files for the languages and the translations are working fine for normal content tags:

```
<li class="font-bold">
    {{ $t('ScholarshipPage.scholBullet3.data') }}
</li>
```

However, I am trying to translate data tags, but they are not working:

Originally I tried

```
pageNavigation: [
  {       
      link: '/information',
      title:  {{ $t('InfoPage.infoLink1.data') }},
  },
],
```

But it throws an error - property assignment expected, so I removed the double braces

```
pageNavigation: [
  { 
      link: '/information',
      title:  $t('InfoPage.infoLink1.data'),
  },
],
```

This throws an error - can't access property "_normalized", next is undefined

Is it possible to use translations in data tags, or will I need to rewrite the tags using standard markup?

thanks

Ok I have updated my menu to o use compute

```
},
  computed: 
        mainMenu [
        {
          title: this.$t('MainMenu.aboutMenu.data'),
          link: '#',
          subMenu: [
            {
              title: this.$t('MainMenu.aboutSubMenu1.data'),
   link: '/about',},     ],
  

data() {
    return {
      SeDB,
      searchToggle: false,
      mobileMenu: false,
      searchInput: null,

    }
},
```

But my page doesn't render at all now

Comment: If you have the whole `pageNavigation` in a `computed` + `title: this.$t('InfoPage.infoLink1.data')`, that should work just fine.

Comment: As told above, the thing to translate needs to be in a `computed` because `data` is static (not reactive if you update a value inside).

Answer (score 2):

Please try this, You can use computed to use translation in data tags.

```
 computed: {
    mainMenu() {
      return [
        { link: '/information', title: this.$t('InfoPage.infoLink1.data')},
      ];
    }
}
```

And for Data tags:

```
data() { return { mainMenu: [ { link: '/information', title: this.$t('InfoPage.infoLink1.data')}, ], } }
```

Comment: And for data tags.

   `  data() {
        return {
          mainMenu: [
            { link: '/information', title: 
              this.$t('InfoPage.infoLink1.data')},
          ],
        }
      } `

Comment: If you have something to add to your original reply, use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73397664/edit), and add it to your reply, specifically code.